# ionic 3 ngx-datatable data-table.ttf data-table.woff font files issues

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Good day all,
When running an ionic 3 app with ngx-datatable, the console returned with 2 errors:
(1)
GET http://localhost:8100/build/fonts/data-table.woff net::ERR_ABORTED   index.js:5465 
(2)
GET http://localhost:8100/build/fonts/data-table.ttf net::ERR_ABORTED :8100/build/fonts/data-table.ttf:1

I copied these two font files into these directories: (1) www\assets\fonts (2) \src\assets\fonts and then rebuild ionic build but with no luck.  I'm not familiar with the ionic build process.  Following is the version info:

cli packages: (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
global packages:
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
System:
    Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
    Node              : v8.9.1
    npm               : 5.5.1
    OS                : Windows 10

ngx-datatable:

"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^11.1.7"

Thanks for your help...

LHLK

Answer (score 0):

After running the npm install no more fonts related errors by default.